# Why is my NodeJS App not working as it should?

Tags: node.js, express

I don't understand what is my mistake but the `app.Method` are not really working.

```
server.js :

//express :
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//middleware :
app.use(express.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false }))

//templating engine :
var ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', ejs);

//public directory :
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//pages:
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello")
    res.render('pages/index')
})

app.get('/post/new', function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/post-new')
})
app.post('post/new', function (err, req) {
    console.log(req.body)
})

//listening 
app.listen(8080, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(`Listening on 8080`)
});
```

I have my directory something like this:

```
node-modules
public
views
--pages
----index.ejs
----post-new.ejs
--partials
package-lock.json
package.json
server.js
```

I don't really understand why is it not working. I have tried adding `console.log(req)` in `app.get`s but they don't really log anything. And sorry for the dumb question.

EDIT: **Answer** is It is `app.use(express.json())` NOT `app.use(express.json)`

Comment: `app.use(express.json)` -> `app.use(express.json())` and it should start working. What's happening is your middleware is not calling `next()` on the request, since you've passed the wrong function in, so none of the requests are trickling down to the rest of the methods.

Comment: How could I miss it _facepalm_ Anyway LOL New Error

Comment: Your `app` and `bodyParser` are also implicitly declared as global variables instead of module-scoped. I recommend starting those lines with `var`, though it looks like you meant to separate them with `,` instead of `;`.

Comment: You are right I changed them. Thanks for the help again. :)